# Entity Framework: Mapped multiple Tables into one Entity -Insert problems

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, crud

Today I have an Entity Framework Question. I have two Tables: Projects and Projects_Rights

[alt text http://www.zaczek.net/EF-stackoverflow.jpg](http://www.zaczek.net/EF-stackoverflow.jpg)

- Projects contains some Projects...
- Project_Rights contains access rights for each Identity (=User) for each Project. This Table is computed by triggers/functions.

Mapping those table into **one** entity was no challenge:

```
class Project
{
    int ID;
    double AufwandGes;
    DateTime CreatedOn;
    ...
    int CurrentIdentity__Implementation__;
    int CurrentAccessRights__Implementation__;
}

<EntitySetMapping Name="Projekt">
  <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(Model.Projekt)">
    <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Projekt">
      <ScalarProperty Name="ID" ColumnName="ID" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="AufwandGes" ColumnName="AufwandGes" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="ChangedOn" ColumnName="ChangedOn" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="CreatedOn" ColumnName="CreatedOn" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="Kundenname" ColumnName="Kundenname" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="Name" ColumnName="Name" />
    </MappingFragment>
    <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Projekt_Rights">
      <ScalarProperty Name="ID" ColumnName="ID" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="CurrentIdentity__Implementation__" ColumnName="Identity" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="CurrentAccessRights__Implementation__" ColumnName="Right" />
    </MappingFragment>
  </EntityTypeMapping>
</EntitySetMapping>
```

Selecting projects either:

```
var prjList = ctx.GetQuery<Project>()
    // This condition is added automatically by a custom Linq Provider
    .Where(p => p.CurrentIdentity__Implementation__ == Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.ID);
```

I've figured out how to prevent Entity Framework from **updating** CurrentIdentity__Implementation__(=Identity) & CurrentAccessRights__Implementation__(=Right). This is done in the SSDL by setting StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed".

```
  <EntityType Name="Projekte_Rights">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="ID" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="Identity" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />
    <Property Name="Right" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />
  </EntityType>
```

I've declared a cascade **delete** in my SQL Server and SSDL. Works great!

My problem is: How can I prevent Entity Framework from **inserting** a record into the Project_Rights table? Adding records there is done by a trigger/function.

Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

**EDIT:**

I found another way. Thanks to Alex for helping me leaving this path.

I've created a View

```
create view Projekte_with_Rights as
select tbl.*, r.[Identity], r.[Right]
from Projekte tbl
inner join Projekte_Rights r on tbl.ID = r.id
```

This View is updatable. To be able to delete a row I implemented this trigger:

```
create trigger Projekte_with_Rights_DeleteTrigger
ON Projekte_with_Rights
INSTEAD OF DELETE AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Projekte WHERE ID in (SELECT ID FROM deleted)
END
```

Now I can map this view as a "table" in Entity Framework. [Identity] and [Rights] are mapped as computed columns.

Another Trigger is now responsible for filling in the correct Identities and Rights. And here I have another Problem. If I insert more then one Row into the Projekte_Rights Table EF claims that a Entity returned more than one Row. but that's another story and out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want more granular control over inserts & updates you need to use StoredProcedures for insert/update/delete operations.

Unfortunately the scope of an update/insert/delete is the Entity, you can't get more granular and configure a Sproc (for one table) and standard T-SQL (for the other table).

This means if you need to override control for the Projekt_Rights table you have to do it for the Projekt table too.

Check out [this sample](http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/using-stored-procedures-for-insert-update-amp-delete-in-an-entity-data-model/) for more.

Note: if you need to do this for insert, unfortunately you have to do it for update and delete too.

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: +1: I was afraid to hear that. Thank you for helping me leaving this way. I will try a solution with updatable views.